# How do I activate a Stack Exchange login (user+pass, i.e. not OpenID)?

Tags: support, login

I searched in the preferences but found nothing, so how do I create a user+password on Stack Exchange, on an account which I've been using with OpenID only?

Answer (score 4):

The "Stack Exchange login" is, itself, just an OpenID service.

To create one, go to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register

Once done, you'll have an OpenID URL to use. (Go to your user profile, click "my logins", then "add more logins..." then "more login options". Then you'll have a field where you can put your Stack Exchange OpenID information.

Once that's set up, you can remove the other OpenID connection you no longer want to use.

Answer (score -1):

You can link it to a google/facebook/etc account by removing your openid account. If you hit "my logins" at the top right of your profile. Other than that you can not make a site login with an existing account. It will still be linked to facebook google or any other authorization provider you choose